# Reading mails using JavaMail

Tags: jakarta-mail, imap, pop3

This question is more about the behavior. I have been using both POP3 and IMAP to access mails in Gmail using JavaMail API. I noticed something and I wanted to clarify my doubts regarding the same.

I am currently retrieving unseen mails from my Inbox. There were a couple of unread mails and I retrieved them using POP3. I switched over to IMAP and read the same inbox and I was able to retrieve the same 2 mails.

I've been recently using JavaMail and I encountered this kind of behavior and I wanted to know if this is the expected behavior?

Comment: There is no such thing as 'unread mail' in POP3.

Comment: ^Can you please elaborate?

Comment: POP3 does not expose any concept besides messages. There are no flags to indicate if something is unread, etc. Beyond all that, GMail's POP3 implementation is highly nonstandard.

Comment: The [JavaMail FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#newmsgs) and [javadocs](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/com/sun/mail/pop3/package-summary.html) might help.

Answer (score 1):

You read your mail, did not delete or change anything, so when you read it again it was still there and unchanged. That's all.